# Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 logs off when I launch anything

Tags: 16.04, gnome, session, logout

Every time I log on and launch something, it logs off. If I log in again and launch something, it either logs off again or launches fine. If it launches okay, then there are no problems for the rest of session. This is very irritating because it takes a while to start a session. How can I fix this?